# 'Observable<Hero[]>' is not assignable to type 'Hero[]'

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm following Angular's [Tour of Heroes Tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#see-it-run) and I'm now trying to integrate observables into my project. After changing my hero.service.ts file to look like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

  constructor() { }

  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return of(HEROES);
  }
}
```

I'm not receiving the following error

> ERROR in src/app/heroes/heroes.component.ts(27,5): error TS2322: Type
>   'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Hero[]'.   Property
>   'includes' is missing in type 'Observable'.

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here. I don't really have an 'includes' property on my hero definition. That class looks like this

```
export class Hero {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

Here is a [link to my project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtfxvn) although I can't get it running in stack blitz

I'll list out the full code here

heroes.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  selectedHero: Hero;

  heroes: Hero[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroes = this.heroService.getHeroes();
  }




}
```

hero.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

  constructor() { }

  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return of(HEROES);
  }
}
```

hero.ts

```
export class Hero {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

mock-heroes.ts

```
import { Hero } from './hero';

export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];
```

Comment: You're trying to assign `Observable<Hero[]>` to `Hero[]` (which is exactly what the error message says).

Comment: Why does that not work though? I'm following along with Angular's tutorial and it works for them. I'm not sure what it means by "property 'includes' is missing in type 'observable<Hero[]'

Comment: What is your version of `rxjs` ? Because since the V6 you have to import `Observable` Object like this : `import { Observable } from 'rxjs;`.

Comment: You should read the following section of the tutorial https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#subscribe-in-heroescomponent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroes = this.heroService.getHeroes();
  }
```

As the error is telling you, `this.heroes` is of type `Hero[]` (hence, an array of `Hero` elements), while `this.heroService.getHeroes();` returns an **observable**, which is of type `Observable<Hero[]>`.

Since you are working with an observable, you have to properly subscribe to it, like this:

```
getHeroes(): void {
   this.heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(result => this.heroes = result);
}
```

Comment: Oh. Okay I understand now. I thought I had done something wrong since it wasn't compiling. Thank you. I'll accept this answer when it lets me.

Comment: I feel like there was no necessity for an answer to this question, as OP most likely missed a key section of the tutorial, which I already pointed out and explains in a better way the solution to his issue.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo But every Question need a answer, comment can't solve everything.

Comment: I'm getting it too

Comment: I had changed
heroes: Hero[]; 
to
heroes: Observable<Hero[]>;

Changed it back and it is working.